# How do I change an element in a list, and keep a copy of the original list?

Tags: python

I've searched around and tried a lot of stuff but I can't get this to work. I think the problem is something to do with how Python list names *point* to the list, rather than *being* the actual list, but I still can't figure it out. The situation is this (it's a list of dictionaries):

```
list_original = [dictionary1, dictionary2, dictionary3]
dictionary2_modified = dictionarymodifier(dictionary2) #some function that modifies the chosen element
list_modified = [i for i in list_original] #makes copy of original list
for i,n in enumerate(dictionary_original):
    if i==1:
        list_modified[1] = dictionary2_modified #replaces element with modified version
return list_original, list_modified
```

And many similar things, but I always either get two of the original list or two of the new list! I add that I'm using python 2.4 and don't have a choice in that.

Many thanks for any help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Mutable vs. Immutable

You need to know the difference between mutable and immutable elements. Namely, both dictionaries and lists in Python are *mutable*. Which means that if you modify it in one place, it is also modified in the other place.

In addition, the variable of mutable type (like `list` or `dict`) can contain immutable elements (eg. `str`), as well as the other way around: variable of immutable type (eg. `tuple`) can contain mutable elements (such as `list` or `dict`).

### Example for mutability

So, this shows the mutability using the example of list:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> b = a
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> b
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> a[2] = 'x'
>>> a
[1, 2, 'x', 4]
>>> b
[1, 2, 'x', 4]
```

### How to obtain a copy of list or dict

To obtain a copy of `list`, you simply can do this instead:

```
new_list = old_list[:]  # the slicing at the end just takes the whole list
```

In case of `dict` this is generally sufficient:

```
new_dict = old_dict.copy()
```

### Nested lists / dicts

However, although lists / dicts that are flat or contain only mutable elements, can be copied the way I showed, to obtain a copy of more complex mutable data structures you need to do something more...

In such case very helpful may be the `copy` module with its [`deepcopy` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy). Documentation of `copy` module says more about its purpose:

> Assignment statements in Python do not copy objects, they create bindings between a target and an object. For collections that are mutable or contain mutable items, a copy is sometimes needed so one can change one copy without changing the other. This module provides generic shallow and deep copy operations (explained below).

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for taking the time to write such a thorough response. I knew it was to do with this mutable business. I had the same problem before with two lists, but I underestimated the effect of having a list of dictionaries in this case. The deepcopy has worked brilliantly.

Answer (score 0):

Is your `dictionarymodifier` actually mutating `dictionary2` in place? If so, the way you build your list is irrelevant.

Simply using `list_modified = list(list_original)` works fine to create a  *shallow* copy of the list, which you can then modify to your heart's content, but only if you don't modify the items **in** the original list (which you can't if they're immutable built-in things like numbers or strings, so beginners often mistake this for a deep copy).

If you really need to copy the list, you can use `copy.deepcopy` to do so.

Comment: Aha, I just understood the slight subtlety to this answer. I've already used deep copy now, but thanks for this, I understand more now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a copy of the list.

```
copy=list(original)
original[0] = None
```